# How to get found view from onView result(ViewInteration

Tags: android, user-interface, testing, android-espresso

for example here is my code:

```
@Test
public void manga_list2() throws Exception {
    onView(withId(R.id.manga_list));
}
```

I try `onView(withId(R.id.manga_list))` result is ViewInteration, I hope get finded View and I try `onView(withId(R.id.manga_list)).viewFinder.getView()` in android studio > watches tool, and i get error:

```
Executing a query on the view hierarchy outside of the main thread (on: Instr: android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner)
```

how to get the view?

**update**

if it cannot, please recommend me other ui testing that can get view directly, the espresso is too black-box

Answer (score 0):

"espresso is too black-box" - exactly the opposite. Below is the code you can use to get the whatever view from your activity. In the example I'm getting the ListView:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class EspressoTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<YourTestActivity> mActivityRule =
        new ActivityTestRule<>(YourTestActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void doSomeStuff() {
        ListView listView = (ListView)mActivityRule.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.manga_list);
    }
}
```

More examples here - [android-testing-templates](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing-templates/tree/master/AndroidTestingBlueprint).